# Throw a derived class in catch scope

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, try-catch, throw

I would like to understand what going wrong in the program that cause that `PE` which is a derived class, is not catching by the `second catch` and display the error like I want.
In the same way, what I have to correct in order to run this simple example

```
class myEx
{
    int errNum;
public:
    myEx(int e) : errNum(e) {}
    virtual void printErr() { cout << errNum << " "; }
};
class subEx : public myEx
{
    string errDesc;
public:
    subEx(int e, string d) : myEx(e), errDesc(d) {}
    void printErr()
    {
        myEx::printErr();
        cout << errDesc << " ";
    }
};
int main()
{
    try
    {
        myEx* pME = new subEx(0, "err 0");
        throw pME;
    }
    catch (myEx* p)
    {
        p->printErr();
        subEx PE(1, "err 1");
        throw PE;
    }
    catch (subEx e)
    {
        e.printErr();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `throw`ing pointer? why catch by pointer, then by value?

Comment: @Jarod42 This is an example I have to understand for my test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `try` block can throw only 1 exception object at a time. It can have multiple `catch` blocks to specify different types of exceptions it wants to catch, but only 1 of them will actually be executed at most, the one that most closely matches the type of exception actually thrown.

If no `catch` blocks match, the exception propagates the call stack until it finds a higher `catch` block that does match.

If a matching `catch` block wants to throw a new exception (which is perfectly legal), you need a higher `try/catch` to catch it.

Also, do not throw/catch exceptions by pointer. Throw them by value instead, and then catch them by reference. Otherwise, you leak the exception object, as the `catch` won't be able to free it correctly when the pointer goes out of scope.

Try this:

```cpp
class myEx
{
    int errNum;
public: 
    myEx(int e) : errNum(e) {} 
    virtual void printErr() const
    {
        cout << errNum << " ";
    } 
}; 

class subEx : public myEx
{
    string errDesc;
public: 
    subEx(int e, string d) : myEx(e), errDesc(d) {}
    void printErr() const
    {
        myEx::printErr();
        cout << errDesc << " ";
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            throw subEx(0, "err 0");
        }
        catch (const myEx &p)
        {
            p.printErr();
            throw subEx(1, "err 1");
        }
    }
    catch (const subEx &e)
    {
        e.printErr();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not work like you think.

All catch blocks apply to preceding try block. You cannot catch in the second catch block what you've thrown in the first catch block. You can however catch that in catch block of one of the functions which directly or indirectly called your function (which is not the case here).

Comment: So If understand you there is no way to throw something in catch block. If I want to throw the second statement `throw PE`, I have to create another try. It's right ?

Comment: @Ronyco123 yes, a `try/catch` only applies to one exception at a time. If you need to catch multiple exceptions (or even one exception multiple times), you need multiple `try/catch`